# StartIndex cannot be less than zero

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

im working on a text-editor and the time i input text on it then i deleted it the error:

> StartIndex cannot be less than zero

pointing this code:

```
String line = rtb.Text.Substring(start, end - start);
```

inside a textchange event:

```
public void TextChangedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
```

further more :

[image]

pls help how can i fix that error! thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, what's the value of `rtb.SelectionStart`?

Comment: i think its 0 sir . i try to get definition and this what i get: public int SelectionStart { get; set; }

Comment: Don't  post your code as an image, just paste as a plain text `;)`

Comment: @SonerGönül sorry about that sir hehe ill just edit it . hope you could help me fix this bug :/

Comment: @Elegiac: Don't *think* it's 0 - look at it in the debugger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously returns `rtb.SelectionStart` zero and your code subtracts -1, with the result -1. The simple solution is

```
if(rtb.SelectionStart > 0)
{
   for(start = rtb.SelectionStart - 1; start > 0; start--)
   {
     if(rtb.Text[start] == '\n') { start++; break; }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'd wrap that around the whole code block from `int start = 0, end = 0;` to `String line = rtb.Text.Substring(start, end - start);`

Comment: ^^thanks a lot this is right . simple logic but awesome result .xD ill accept this answer after 5mins ;)

Comment: @Adrian @ Elegiac Not around the whole block `int start = 0, end = 0` should be outer the if. Otherwise the program won't work. Just see my code, thats all.

Comment: @Kai awesome :)  I hadn't thought of it that way, but you're quite correct.

Comment: @Kai i have different question but not related to this^^ i mean i think bug was related to this that you might know also :) can i?